# Show MySQL data record NULL on table

Tags: mysql

i have data on MySQL like in the picture below
[image]

when i use query

```
select
    *
from
    aps
where
    kategori not like '%high'
    and
    kategori not like '%medium'
    and
    kategori not like '%standar';
```

thats not showing anything.

And, how to show that data NULL on that table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` values in SQL cause comparison operations (e.g. `LIKE`, `NOT LIKE`, `=`, etc) to behave differently: A `NULL` value cannot be directly compared to a non-`NULL` value. This is different to most programming languages where the `==` and `!=` operators are defined for `null` references and pointers (e.g. C#, Java, C++, etc).

**In SQL use the `IS NULL` operator to test for `NULL` specifically.**

So in your case, the query should be:

```
select
    *
from
    aps
where
    (
        kategori IS NULL
    )
    OR
    (
        kategori not like '%high'
        and
        kategori not like '%medium'
        and
        kategori not like '%standar'
    )
```

Alternatively, use `COALESCE` in a subquery to provide a non-`NULL` value if you intend to use `kategori` in other operations where `NULL` values may be undesirable due to the complexity handling `IS NULL` specifically:

```
SELECT
    sq.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            COALESCE( kategori, '' ) AS kategori2 -- use an empty string instead of NULL
    ) AS sq
WHERE
    kategori2 NOT LIKE '%high'
    AND
    kategori2 NOT LIKE '%medium'
    AND
    kategori2 NOT LIKE '%standar';
```